# Slide (animate) bg image position on navigation bar using CSS

Tags: css, background, navigation, jquery-animate, position

I found this bit of code elsewhere on this forum and would like to know how I can get the same effect with a navigation bar.

So I would have 7 text links, and when you mouse over one, the image should slide to that bit of text. It would need to be in a different start position on each page (highlighting the current page on the nav bar)

This is the html:

```
<div class="box">
<a href"#">Home</a>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.rollover a {
    background: url(img/bg_nav_slide.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    width: 920px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
.rollover a:hover {
    background-position: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
}   
.box {
    background: url(img/bg_nav_slide.png) no-repeat;;
    border: 0;
    width: 920px;
    height: 50px;    
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
    background-position: 40px 0;
}
.box p {
    text-indent: 2px;
}
```

Comment: I think this might be what you're looking for http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/lavalamp2

Comment: Is it not possible to do with pure CSS?

Answer (score 2):

That's the Lavalamp effect; you can find a pure CSS solution here:

http://codepen.io/iamvdo/pen/GsIxk

Answer (score 0):

POSITIVE:
You can use any number of menu items without changing the code and use this code for many such elements in your project

NEGATIVE:
You have a fixed item width.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_btn_container">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #nav_btn_container > div {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    width: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    height: 40px;
}

#nav_btn_container {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #111;
    background-image: url("icons/btn.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 10px 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 40px;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(NAV_BTN_CONTAINER).on("mouseenter", "div", function(event){
       let i = $(this).index();
       $(NAV_BTN_CONTAINER).css("background-position-x", i*120 + "px");
    });
```

icons/btn.svg:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="120" height="40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="8" ry="8" width="120" height="40" style="fill:#191919;"/>
</svg>
```